# Running Pages from Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi there,
I have a bit of a weird question!  I've just started using WordPress, and have taken over an existing project.  This is a wordpress site that was modified heavily.  I have managed to install wordpress on it.
I can access the generic "'test', just another WordPress site intereface" pages.

However I don't know how to access individual site pages that the previous project runners have created.

Sorry this is a bit vague but grateful for your help!

Comment: Was the previous "site" a wordpress site?

Answer (score 0):

The "Pages", are actually really just posts from the database that are layed out in a different style. You'll have to database mine to find the "pages".

At least that's the way I had to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try some plugins to import your post from other wordpress

that will help you to import and export you all pages even post (depend on selection, what you import)

you can download plugin here >>

after install you can c under setting menu

> `https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/`